# Visual Studio Code reports python 3.7.3 Interpreter even though pointing to 3.8.8 exe

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Although new Anaconda Environments shows base (root) latest Python 3.8.8, Visual Studio Code reports python 3.7.3 in Jupyter .ipynb notebook:

[image]

However, Settings -> Default Interpreter Path definitely points to C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3 (it was installed for all users) whose Python.exe is indeed 3.8.8150. And code verifies it does seem to be the 3.8.8:

```
import sys
print (sys.version)

3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 15:08:03) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Further, I believe it must be 3.8 as it uses non-3.7 ":=" Assignment Expressions https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html

```
a = np.arange(11)
if (n := len(a)) > 10:
    print(f"List is too long ({n} elements, expected <= 10)")
```

I've uninstalled, rebooted and installed latest Anaconda 2021.05 and Visual Studio Code 1.57.1 (because VSC disappeared from the Anaconda tiles), still same issue. On another Windows 10 PC, VSC shows 3.8.8 no prob, although Default Interpreter Path to Anaconda3\Python.exe is slightly different via C:\users folder (as installed for own user only).

Is this just an annoying VSC misreporting bug or something more nefarious and I'm missing something? Anyone else have this problem on Anaconda python versions with Visual Studio Code (which is otherwise excellent)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by running that code in the notebook:

```
import sys
sys.version
```

I didn't notice at first (testing across a couple of workspaces), but it updates the kernal picker in top right corner. I used the VSC "Help -> Report Issue" to add it to their GitHub Issues and got a response to do that: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/6526

So it's just a caching/flushing issue in the kernal picker, no major problem, and this code does seem to clear it.